# MySQL: IF in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am just getting my feet wet with stored procedures. According to the tutorials that I have seen, this should be valid (MySQL 5.5):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE someFunction ( a VARCHAR(256),  b VARCHAR(256) )
    BEGIN
        DECLARE haveAllVariables INT;
        SET haveAllVariables = 1;

    IF     a = "" THEN SET haveAllVariables = 0
    ELSEIF b = "" THEN SET haveAllVariables = 0
    END IF;
```

However, it is throwing this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ELSEI
F b = "" THEN SET haveAllVariables = 0
```

Where is the error in my syntax?

Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon

```
CREATE PROCEDURE someFunction ( a VARCHAR(256),  b VARCHAR(256) )
    BEGIN
        DECLARE haveAllVariables INT;
        SET haveAllVariables = 1;

    IF     a = "" THEN SET haveAllVariables = 0;
    ELSEIF b = "" THEN SET haveAllVariables = 0;
    END IF;
```

Comment: Thank you! It should have been obvious!

Answer (score 11):

Stored procedures are a bit tricky.  But here is an example I tested and posted for you.  In your example you were missing a couple of semicolons and the final "END".

```
DELIMITER $$
  CREATE PROCEDURE someFunction ( a VARCHAR(256),  b VARCHAR(256) )
  BEGIN
    DECLARE haveAllVariables INT;
    SET haveAllVariables = 1;

  IF  a = '' THEN 
    SET haveAllVariables = 0;
  ELSEIF b = '' THEN 
    SET haveAllVariables = 0;
  END IF;
END $$
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually the `END` is quite a way further down, in code that the parser didn't even get to yet! But it was in fact the missing semicolon that was my problem.